# Does ISKCON consider itself an Astika Sampradaya?

Tags: iskcon

An Astika sampradaya is one that places the infallible authority of the Vedas first. There are claims for instance, that ISKCON leaders believe that Srimad Bhaagavatam is higher in authority than Vedas. What this means, potentially, is that if ever there is a conflict of interpretation between the Vedas and Bhaagavatam, ISKCON's position will default in support of Bhagaavatam over Vedas - Is this true?

Given the potential for controversy with this question, answers that source their evidence *authoritatively* are only appreciated (books published by any ISKCON press agencies proclaiming their affiliation (or lack thereof) or direct links to statements in interviews by ISKCON's upper echelon leaders proclaiming this or otherwise)

Comment: ISKCON believe in vedanta. Doesn't that make them astika?

Comment: @KrishnaShweta An authoritative answer to this question can be used in the future. In any case, astika means considering vedas as highest authority across all other scriptures. This is the point I am interested to get clarified on.

Comment: I will answer the question if you change it from ISKCON to Gaudiya Sampradaya

Comment: Thank you for the consideration but I'm actually interested in the question as it pertains to ISKCON. @RaRe

Comment: Learned people in ISKCON will obviously not see conflict b/w the two, they will interpret the statement properly.

Comment: @RaRe If you can substantiate (i.e., give evidence) for your comment above regarding why there cannot be an answer to this question or provide evidence for the lack of conflict given the requirements for what can be accepted as authoritative evidence (as mentioned in the body of the question), you can add that as answer as well for consideration.

Comment: I can't substantiate, that is my opinion having observed iskcon.

Comment: See the Sri Vaishnava answer about puranas purpose#2  https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/32620/2612. Seems like Ramanujacharya also interprets Vedas with the help of puranas, How will you know the conflict then?. Vedas would be interpreted with the help of puranas.

Comment: Can you give a source of your statement - _astika sampradaya is one that places the infallible authority of the vedas first?_, Astika would simply mean one who believes in the existence of Brahman or Bhagavaan or astika would mean one who believes in the authority of vedas or literatures which emphasise atman and god consciousness.