# What Advaita tells about Mlechha, Caste system, Varna Sanskara?

Tags: advaita, caste-system, adi-shankaracharya, varnashrama

What Advaita tells about

- Mleccha can change religion to Hinduism?

  (Yes means which varna they will come. No means explanation of why they should not change religion)
- [Please answer this question about varna dharma](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/43404/does-shankaracharya-of-puri-consider-that-varna-is-based-on-birth-is-this-consi)
- Then any justify to a Chandala

Answer (score 2):

Excellent question. The two are separate matters. Advaitha Vedanta is a philosophy of mind and spirit, based on Upanishads, Bhagavad Gita and Brahma-sutras. It discusses the three realities; Brahman, Jiva and Jagat and prescribes a methodology for achieving the highest goal - moksha. The Varnashrama Dharma is an economic theory not a philosophy. It is a complex system for social management in the age of a balanced economy. The system in its pure form aims at the optimization of the three goals of human life - the tripod of material happiness; Dharma - occupation and value system for the society and individual, artha - production and expenditure of wealth, and kama - enjoyment, recreation, procreation etc. These two aspects of life are known as trivarga - the three material goals of the householder and apavarga - ultimate liberation from samsara - the goal of the renunciates. So one can indeed study and practice Vedanta without any reference whatsoever to the caste system. One can also practice the caste system without any reference to Vedanta - which is generally the case. The message of the Gita is an integrated system and all three goals of human happiness should be striven for, but without attachment but rather in a spirit of renunciation.
I want to be brief and just remind you that the caste-system is an extremely complex network of kinship and social relations involving transactions of goods and services. It has been very flexible over the generations but in its present form is a complete corruption and travesty - since society has dramatically changed since its formulation. The problems of the caste system are the same as any economic system - corruption, greed, oppression, exploitation etc.. There is no economic system in the world that is pure and benevolent - neither capitalist or communist.

Comment: Where do you find advaita discusses 3 realities?

Comment: Did you answered my question

Comment: @PrasannaR https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/13626/19211

Comment: @PashamVishnuVardhanGoud Please re read the answer again. There is a difference between Philosophy and Society. I personally follow Hinduism because the philosophy of Vedanta is unassailable and trumps all other religious theologies. Vedanta is completely free of caste considerations and is an objective philosophy of life. Vedanta is open to every one regardless of sex, gender, caste or race. Caste considerations are based upon spiritual ignorance and self-interest - both of which are condemned by Vedanta.

Comment: @PashamVishnuVardhanGoud Aatma Bodha 11: Because of Its association with different conditionings (Upadhis) such ideas as caste, colour and position are super-imposed upon the Atman, as flavour, colour, etc., are super-imposed on water.

Comment: Nirvana Shaktam: Neither the division into castes and stages of life, nor the rules of conduct and duties of the various castes and stages of life apply to me. I have no need for dharana, dhyana or yoga, etc. Since the notions of 'I' and 'mine' which are due to identification with the not-self (body, mind and organs) have gone, I remain as the one auspicious self free from all attributes. I have neither death nor fear of death, nor caste; Nor was I ever born, nor had I parents, friends, and relations; I have neither Guru, nor disciple; I am Existence Absolute, Knowledge Absolute,Bliss Absolute

Comment: Upadesha Sahasri 5.1 : People do not receive Self-knowledge on account of the fear that their duties (according to their castes and orders of life) would be destroyed like Udanks who did not accept genuine nectWhen they are considered to be one's own caste etc. becomes the cause of injunctions like a dead body. They do not, therefore, belong to the Self. The Self would otherwise become the non-Self.

Comment: Upadeshasahasri 
Chapter 15 verse 5: When they are considered to be one's own caste etc. becomes the cause of injunctions like a dead body. They do not, therefore, belong to the Self. The Self would otherwise become the non-Self.
Chapter 15 verse 8: After giving up caste etc., which are the causes of duties, a wise man should (constantly) remember, from the scriptures, his own real nature which is incompatible with causes of duties

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru this 3 you specified never stated about 3 classification Bhrama, Jiva and Jagat.. What it was saying.. Vyavarika -- while doing day to day life dont take my illusion concept of the world.. similarly shankarachary defines the boudary of mithya.. so that people doesnt take it in litireally he never differentiated Bhrama, jiva and jagat, it was sriramanacharya while describing reality he says about 3 things of real existence.. not shankaracharya as you claim..

Comment: @PrasannaR First of all, Every Vedantic school speaks of Bramha Jiva and Jagat only. Learn spelling of Ramanujacharya first. Btw Ramanujacharya and Shankaracharya have already refuted your Dwaitha. Dwaitha is apparently false and anyone who reads Upanishads and Gita can refute it easily. Your theory of Panchabheda is absolute nonsence which isn't found anywhere in Vedas/Upanishads. Why are you so obsessed to comment on Advaitha by assuming it as something else ? And why do you intervene in answers of Advaitha? Follow your school and let us follow ours. Hinduism isn't Abrahmic religion.

Comment: See I'm not commenting on advaita it's your statement that makes advaita vada veranda vada you are saying things which advaita vehemently opposed like reality of Brahms jive and hagar you have to replace the 3 with whatever other blog points out

Comment: @PrasannaR Why are you diverting topic? Advaitha says Brahman alone appears as Jiva, Jagat and Ishwara. Brahman alone is real. All Vedanta schools focus on discussion between these 3 - Jiva Jagat and Brahman/Ishwara. Even Ramanuja says Brahman alone is real and Non Dual. Though he makes classification in it unlike Madhva who says all 3 are seperate like Islam despite Texts saying World comes from Brahman and dissolves into it. Even a Cow which eats Grass knows Dwaitha is true. Tell me something new. Watch this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Dk4EIe-qyk

Comment: Answer the video I mentioned

Comment: Im never here for argument to win over advaita right from the start im only  saying Advaita never accepts reality of jagat.. why you put them as if advaita told..It never differentiate it was only   after madvacharya they started 4 Jiva, SB, NB and jagat Mithya.. but neverever advaita says they are rea.. You are only digressing.. Regarding cow eats grass anology its a fun.. just because Cow knows Grass is different.. since you are human with intellect think that grass and cow are safe.. so your intellect is raised many folds.. Wow what fun.. i cannot stop laughing at this lol

Comment: @PashamVishnuVardhanGoud Who cares of Puri Shankara? According to Manu 95% of Dwijas are Outcastes. We all are Sudras now. Dharma Sastras are no longer applicable. Read here since you follow Swami Vivekananda : https://muktipadablog.wordpress.com/2015/12/10/vedic-study-is-open-for-all/
Meditate and realise Brahman. Study Upanishads. Who is stopping you??

Comment: @PrasannaR Advaitha speaks from 3 Levels of Reality. At Vyavaharika level, duality and reality of universe is accepted. Study some basics lol. Madhva interpretation of Upanishads is twisted and false. Watch that vedio or atlest read Atma Bodha and Tattva Bodha. 
With the mind harmonised by Yoga he sees the Self abiding in all beings and all beings in the Self; he sees the same everywhere.(Gita 6.30)
One who worships a separate deity thinking that the deity is completely different from himself, he is ignorant; he is like a utilitarian animal to the deities. Brhadaranyaka Upanishad (4.10)

Comment: When a man sees the whole variety of beings as resting in the One, and spreading forth from That alone, he then becomes Brahman.(Gita 13.31)
From the Self is life from the Self is desire from the Self is love from the Self is ether from the Self is light from the Self are the waters from the Self is appearance and disappearance from the Self is food.(Chandogya Upanishad 7.26.1)

Comment: Manu 12.119 : The Self alone is all the gods; everything subsists in the Self; it is the Self that brings about the connection of these embodied beings with actions.
Manu 12.123 : This some people call ‘Agni’; others, ‘Manu-Prajāpati’; others, ‘Indra’; others, ‘Prāṇa’; and yet others, ‘the Eternal Brahman.

Comment: @PrasannaR  These flowing rivers that go towards the ocean, when they have reached the ocean, sink into it, their name and form vanish, and people speak of the ocean only, exactly thus these sixteen parts of the spectator that go towards the person, when they have reached the person, sink into him, their name and form vanish, and people speak of the one person only, and he becomes without parts and immortal.”  
(Prasna Up 6.5)
I will stop here because you are just a fanatic Dwaithan who doesn't even know basics of Advaitha. We accept reality and duality of Universe from Vyavaharika Level.

Comment: That us what I said that is not coming out clearly in your answer read throughout your arguments and mine who is consistent on the answers interpretation it's only your last comment clearly says reality only at  transactional level reality is subjective